# How to fix missing instance in google cloud big table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I have a problem when I do tutorial quickstart cbt (https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/quickstart-cbt) when I create the table by using command cbt createtable my-table and it shows me error missing an instance

> jurarut_subcheevaanan@cloudshell:~ (my-project-test-big-table)$ sudo
> echo project = my-project-test-big-t able > ~/.cbtrc
>
> jurarut_subcheevaanan@cloudshell:~ (my-project-test-big-table)$ sudo
> echo instance = quickstart-instance >> ~/.cbtrc
>
> jurarut_subcheevaanan@cloudshell:~ (my-project-test-big-table)$ cbt
> createtable my-table
> 2019/03/27 10:24:38 -creds flag unset, will use gcloud credential
>
> 2019/03/27 10:24:40 Missing -instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the Quickstart tutorial and it is working as expected. All the steps were executed successfully.

After taking a look at your error logs, it seems that the project name might not have been set up properly, there seems to be an extra space in the name.

> (my-project-test-big-table)$ sudo echo project = my-project-test-big-t
>   able > ~/.cbtrc

It appears that there is a space between `my-project-test-big-t` and `able`. In that case the command can't find the project which of course will also fail to find the instance name.

As I mentioned, the Quickstart is working perfectly. Make sure that when you setup the project name it is set up correctly, if you are still getting the issue, start afresh in a different directory.

Comment: Thank a lot. I'm just newbie in here. I already fix it. That work!